# Calculus Question about maximize profits

Tags: calculus

A small company makes t-shirts. They can be produced for $2/shirt. The shirts have been selling for \$5 each and at this price tourists have been buying 4000 shirts/month. The owner plans to raise the price of shirts and expects that for each \$1 increase in price 400 fewer shirts will be sold each month. What price should be charged per shirt to maximize profits?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: Hint: Make a linear equation in cost/shirt

Comment: Hint: $$\text{Profit in dollars}=(3+n)(4000-400n).$$